# Trying to display a modal in react js when a button is clicked

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to display a modal in react js when I click a button but for some reason it doesn't work.
 This is my modal component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Modal, ModalHeader, Button, ModalBody, ModalFooter } from "reactstrap";

class InstructionsModal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Modal>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">Guide</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <h4>Centered Modal</h4>
          <p>
            Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio,
            dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta
            ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.
          </p>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="danger" onClick={this.props.onHide}>
            Close
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
export default InstructionsModal;
```

This is welcome class in which I call the component `onclick` on the button called instructions:

```
let closeModal = () => {
      this.setState({ viewModal: false });
    }; 


               <ButtonToolbar>
              <Button onClick={() => this.setState({ viewModal: true })}>
                <Nav>Instructions</Nav>
              </Button>
              <InstructionsModal
                show={this.state.viewModal}
                onHide={closeModal}
              />
            </ButtonToolbar>
```

Any help thanks or any alternative way of doing this?

Comment: Read documentation https://reactstrap.github.io/components/modals/#app

Comment: @SargisIsoyan i have thats why i dont know it....i have tried all their example as it is but not working

Answer (score 1):

try below code.

```
import {
  Button,
  Container,
  InputGroup,
  FormControl,
  Row,
  Col,
  Modal
} from "react-bootstrap";

  this.state = {
    modalShow: false,
    title: "title",
    message: "message"
   }

  handleShow() {
    this.setState({ modalShow: true });
  }

  handleClose() {
    this.setState({ modalShow: false });
  }


 render() {
//Note: this is sample code
  <Button id="modalButton" variant="primary" onClick={this.handleShow}></Button>

        <Modal show={this.state.modalShow} onHide={this.handleClose}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>{this.state.title}</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body><p>{this.state.message}</p></Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.handleClose}>
              Close
            </Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
}
```

Comment: see the button i want to click on is another class not in the same class

Comment: it doesn't matter I also have such experience. Do you have idea about props and state. then you can pass modal data to child class. OR I can share my experience

Comment: i have idea about props i have been doing this with props

Comment: can u do one thing write simple modal where it can be oppened by click from another class in codesandbox?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-tesla-y80p0  I added my code. It's work for me . but in hear no pop up was not show even alert() so modal also not showing . but  you can try with local

Comment: im still getting this error no matter what i do in console Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: Can you replace my codesandbox code with your code. then focus on more to your issue. As use can see there console also doesn't have any error. Please refer this  https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4477

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-butterfly-6wqrx check this click instruction button n see the erros

Comment: you can not use this way to .js files. you can use some functions or const and call to that const through the jsx files. Please set it to jsx

Comment: ohhh . please refer your one now. I was remove isOpen from your code

Answer (score 0):

you have to set props of modal to show.
Try this, if it will help you.

```
    <Modal
        isOpen={this.state.viewModal}>
        //Your rest JSX here
    </Modal>
```

Comment: Here is a minor mistake in your code..instead of `this.state.viewModal`, it should be `this.props.show` as per his code.

Comment: react-dom.development.js:26618 Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: based on your error, you might forget imports. can you please check again ?

Comment: @RaviKhunt i have all the imports

Answer (score 0):

In `InstructionsModal` component you are passing `show` props but that props are not being used in that component. Add `isOpen={this.props.show}` attribute in `Modal` component.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Modal, ModalHeader, Button, ModalBody, ModalFooter } from "reactstrap";

class InstructionsModal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Modal isOpen={this.props.show}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">Guide</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <h4>Centered Modal</h4>
          <p>
            Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio,
            dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta
            ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.
          </p>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="danger" onClick={this.props.onHide}>
            Close
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
export default InstructionsModal;
```

Comment: i get a error when i do that react-dom.development.js:26618 Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: It seems like you have forget to copy last line `export default InstructionsModal;` if you have copied my code. Don't copy whole code instead add an attribute `isOpen={this.props.show}` in `Modal` component. @dave

Comment: Where are you using `InstructionsModal` component? Check of export statement in that component @dave

Comment: export default InstructionsModal; thast the last line i have

Comment: have you exported `welcome` class?if possible please share code of `welcome class`@dave

Comment: yess the welcome class is 300+ lines u want all of that

Comment: Is there any export statement in that file? @dave

Comment: yes export default welcome ...this is the import for the model class import InstructionsModal from "./instructionsmodal";

Answer (score 0):

You didn't have create the state to open the model like:

```
class InstructionsModal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
     viewModal:flase
  }
```

then you can open and close model like that:

```
//for open Model**
handleOpen=()=>{
this.setState({viewModal:true});
}

//for close**
handleClose=()=>{
this.setState({viewModal:false});
}
```

Comment: doesnt help mate